Error in using call by reference with function to change the head of a singly linked list
I'm learning linked lists in C, and have come across an error when trying to add a value at beginning of a linked list using functions
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};
void printlist(struct node *head){
    struct node *current = head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("------------------------\n");
}
void addatbegin(struct node **head,int x){
    struct node *new;
    new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->val = x;
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}
int main(){
    struct node *head;
    struct node *h;
    h = &head;
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->val=2;
    head->next= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next->val = 3;
    printlist(head);
    addatbegin(h,4);
    printlist(head);
}

in the function addatbegin(struct node **head,int x), i gave a double pointer to try and use pass by reference to change the head of the linked list.The code runs and works, However im getting these errors/warnings.
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:33:7: warning: assignment to ‘struct node *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct node **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   33 |     h = &head;
      |       ^
main.c:40:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘addatbegin’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   40 |     addatbegin(h,4);
      |                ^
      |                |
      |                struct node *
main.c:23:31: note: expected ‘struct node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’
   23 | void addatbegin(struct node **head,int x){
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
2
3
------------------------
4
2
3
------------------------

How do I fix this?

The compiler warning is telling you what you need to know. You're passing a struct node * rather than a struct node **. You need to use & to pass the address of the head pointer.
int main(void) {
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!head) {
        return 1;
    }

    head->val = 2;
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!head->next) {
        free(head);
        return 1;
    }

    head->next->val = 3;
    head->next->next = NULL;
    printlist(head);
    addatbegin(&head, 4);
    printlist(head);

    free(head->next);
    free(head);
}

Other notes:

Don't cast malloc.
Check that malloc succeeded.
You need to set the next pointer of the final node to NULL if you want the behavior of printlist to be defined.
Free your dynamically allocated memory.
You can avoid passing a pointer to a pointer by defining a struct list which itself contains a pointer to the head and then addatbegin acts on a struct list *.


okayy thank you so much

what is casting malloc and why shouldnt we cast it

I edited that link into my answer.
